# When changing the amount of displayed data is executed several consecutive identical queries?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Why when changing the amount of data, several identical get requests are executed.

> [HPM] GET /api/users/get_all?search=&order=asc&pageSize=25&page=1 ->
>   http://localhost:5000 
>   GET
>   /api/users/get_all?search=&order=asc&pageSize=25&page=1 200 21.551 ms
>   - 701
>
> [HPM] GET /api/users/get_all?search=&order=asc&pageSize=25&page=1 ->
>   http://localhost:5000 
>   GET
>   /api/users/get_all?search=&order=asc&pageSize=25&page=1 200 18.328 ms
>   - 701

Answer (score 0):

there will be always 2 calls for HTTP Method call 1st Call is with `OPTION` and other one is your actual `GET` Call.

[Click Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) for See explanation why `Options` method will call.

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribing (and never unsubscribing) in a repeately called method. With every call of the method a subscription is added. As a result with every call of the method the subscription callback is more often called. Please init your subscriptions in ngOnInit, like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);
    // other subscriptions
}
```

And don't forget to unsubscribe when your component dies. There are plenty of examples how to do this.